# Merge data sets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Problem statement: I have data in sheet1 and sheet2. I need to merge these data on basis of Unique id's(UID) which are mentioned for both data set. I need to merge "Reviewer" and "local" data in sheet1 data set.I have tried Vlookup but did not work for me. Below is the pic mentions data set 1 and data set 2 with final output expected

[image]

Comment: There is no Pic in the post. Edit your question and insert data from both sheet. Then also post your formula you have tried. Then explain what you want to do?

Comment: hi have tried the Vlookup formula to match the UIDs but i am not sure how i can merge these two datas.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you must use Vlookup in data set 2, creating new columns with Vlookup for each data you want from data set 1.
My excel is in Portuguese, the image shows the form PROCV, but in English is VLOOKUP.

=VLOOKUP($I3,$A$3:$E$100,2,FALSE)

[image]

[image]

With all the data gathered in data set 2, select all data from data set 2, and create a pivot table by ordering the data the way you want.

[image]